# Wanted - chat script for Huawei E8372

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, usb, ppp

I've just acquired a "Huawei E8372" USB dongle. I'm trying to connect to Tesltra (Australia). I switched off the wifi function of the dongle. I've managed to get the dongle recognised as `/dev/USB1` using `usb_modeswitch`. I'm using raspbian stretch. I've created the following scripts:

`/etc/ppp/peers/telstra`:

```
connect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/ppp/telstra"
/dev/ttyUSB1
115200
noipdefault
usepeerdns
defaultroute
replacedefaultroute
persist
noauth
debug
```

`/etc/ppp/telstra`:

```
ABORT 'NO CARRIER'
ABORT 'NO DIALTONE'
ABORT 'BUSY'
ABORT 'ERROR'
ABORT 'NO ANSWER'
'' 'ATZ'
OK 'AT&F'
OK 'ATQ0 V1 E1'
OK 'AT&D2 &C1'
OK 'AT+FCLASS=0'
OK 'ATS0=0'
OK 'AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","telstra.internet"'
OK 'ATDT*99#'
CONNECT ''
```

I get the following in my syslog when I enter 'pppd call telstra':

```
Mar 31 16:32:22 raspberrypi chat[1273]: abort on (NO CARRIER)
Mar 31 16:32:22 raspberrypi chat[1273]: abort on (NO DIALTONE)
Mar 31 16:32:22 raspberrypi chat[1273]: abort on (BUSY)
Mar 31 16:32:22 raspberrypi chat[1273]: abort on (ERROR)
Mar 31 16:32:22 raspberrypi chat[1273]: abort on (NO ANSWER)
Mar 31 16:32:22 raspberrypi chat[1273]: send (ATZ^M)
Mar 31 16:32:22 raspberrypi chat[1273]: expect (OK)
Mar 31 16:32:23 raspberrypi chat[1273]: 33^@^@^@^V
Mar 31 16:32:23 raspberrypi chat[1273]: [^O'^Zd^F]`^@^@^@^@$^@^A~^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^H[^O^?~'^Zd^?^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^V:^@^E^B^@^@^A^@^O^@@"^@^@^@^A^D^@^@^@^?^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^?
Mar 31 16:32:33 raspberrypi chat[1273]: ^@^@^@33^@^@^@^AT%j^VjU^F]`^@^@^@^@ :^?~^@^@^@^@^@^@^@V%j^?~^VjU^?^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^F^@Uv@H^G^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^E^A^@^@^@^@^E
Mar 31 16:32:49 raspberrypi chat[1273]: 4^A^AT%j^VjU33^@^@^@^AT%j^VjU^F]`^@^@^@^@ :^?~^@^@^@^@^@^@^@V%j^?~^VjU^?^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^F^@Uv@H^G^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^E
Mar 31 16:33:07 raspberrypi chat[1273]: alarm
Mar 31 16:33:07 raspberrypi chat[1273]: Failed
Mar 31 16:33:07 raspberrypi pppd[1194]: Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/ppp/telstra finished (pid 1272), status = 0x3
Mar 31 16:33:07 raspberrypi pppd[1194]: Connect script failed
Mar 31 16:33:08 raspberrypi pppd[1194]: Exit.
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for reformatting my post.  I don't quite know how you did it, but I'll try next time!

This device does not use ppp or a chat script.  It creates a virtual network device.

I found the answer here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=159344

I put

`max_usb_current=1`

in /boot/config.txt, and

`ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1f01", RUN+="/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 0x1f01 -V 0x12d1 -P 0x1405 -J"`

in /etc/udev/rules.d/70-usb-modeswitch.rules.

Apologies if formatting not right!

Comment: formatting is not difficult: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/editing-help (to see in detail what have changed: click on "edited", then you can see the revisions https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/82091/revisions and click on the "side-by-side markdown" button)